# Fill column based on other columns- SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, conditional-statements, case, multiple-columns

I am interested in performing:

Insert values to a new column, based on values in a different column (same table)
for example:
original column- productName
original column- store_id
target column- final

in this case, I wish to insert in "final" a product name shortcut, concatenated with the store_id.

this is an example of the end result-

| productName | store_id | final |
| --- | --- | --- |
| phone | 001 | pho_001 |
| phone | 014 | pho_014 |
| truck | 022 | tru_022 |
| guitar | 022 | tar_022 |
| phone | 004 | pho_004 |

I wish to create conditions- if the productName is 'phone'- insert 'pho' along with the store id.
if the product name is 'truck' insert 'tru' along with the store id and so on.
there is a desecrate type of products (about 9) so conditions could be applied for final name.

the table is large, and I am looking for a solution that would apply to all rows. not inserting one by one.

note- the shortcut in final is not necessarily built from the first 3 letters of the product

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression in the `UPDATE` statement to concatenate what you want:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET final = CASE productname
              WHEN 'phone' THEN 'pho'
              WHEN 'truck' THEN 'tru'   
              WHEN 'guitar' THEN 'tar'
              WHEN .....
              ELSE .....
            END || '_' || store_id;
```